# RSS Feed setting limit for email subscriptions

Tags: rss

Hello I set my RSS feed limit to 100 but am getting complaints that when subscribing by email they are sent 100 emails.

I would like a Feed Reader to load all 100, but when subscribing by email set the limit to 10.’

Is there a code I can use in functions file to achieve this?

Thanks!

Comment: How are you implementing email subscriptions? Also please do not ask multiple questions in one, that makes it easier to handle and provide specific complete answers.

Comment: That is not WordPress functionality, it doesn't provide email subscription to feeds out of the box.

Comment: Nothing is handling the email subscriptions but in certain browsers like Opera for example if my RSS icon is clicked (href="domain.com/feed") it brings up a subscribe via email option.

Comment: No word on this? Hmmm can I clear up my question in any way? Thanks.

Comment: The word is the same — WordPress itself doesn't do this. You need to figure out what does for starters.

Comment: OK thanks, I was trying to avoid any plugins for RSS feeds but will look around.